# Login function not working in Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-redux, firebase-authentication

Firebase Authentication is not working properly. I am building an app using firebase as the database. In the login part of my app, the sign-in and register functions are not working properly.

Login.js:

```
import {React, useState} from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { auth } from './firebase';
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import {login} from './features/counter/userSlice'
import './Login.css';

function Login() {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [name, setName] = useState("");

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const register = () => {
        if (!name) {
            return alert('Please Enter a full name');
        }

        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userAuth) => {
            userAuth.user.updateProfile({
                displayName: name
            })

            .then(() => {
                dispatch(login({
                    email: userAuth.user.email,
                    uid: userAuth.user.uid,
                    displayName: name
                }));

            });
        }).catch((error) => alert(error));
    };
    const loginToApp = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then(userAuth => {
            dispatch(login({
                email: userAuth.user.email,
                uid: userAuth.user.uid,
                displayName: userAuth.user.displayName,
            }))
        }).catch((error) => alert(error));
    };

  return (
    <div className="login">
        <img src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/linkedin-logo-png-transparent.png" alt=""/>

        <form>
            <input value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} placeholder="Full name (required when registering)" type="text"/>
            <input value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} placeholder="Email" type="email"/>
            <input value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} placeholder="Password" type="password"/>

            <button type="submit" onClick={loginToApp}>Sign In</button>
        </form>

        <p>Not a member?
            <span className="login_register" onClick={register}>Register Now!</span>
        </p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

App.js:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import MainPage from './MainPage';
import routes from './routes';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectUser } from './features/counter/userSlice';
import { auth } from './firebase';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {logout, login} from './features/counter/userSlice';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Login from './Login';

function App() {
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(userAuth => {
      if(userAuth)
      {
        dispatch(login({
          email: userAuth.email,
          uid: userAuth.uid,
          displayName: userAuth.displayName
        }));
      } else {
          dispatch(logout());
      }
    })
  }, [dispatch])

  return (
    <div className="App">

        <Header/>

        {!user ? <Login/> : (
          <div className="App_Body">
          <MainPage/>
        </div>
        )}

        
        
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I am also using redux which I do not have any prior experience of.

When I enter the name, email and password for registering, the register function saves the data into the firestore database but it does not log me in to my app. The sign function also has the same issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What does 'saves the data' mean specifically? What data and where is it saved? By default, data cannot be written without authenticating so how do you know it's "not working"? Also, it's important to troubelshoot before posting questions; Did you step through the code line by line, examining the flow and vars along the way until you find something unexpected? If not, do that and post the results and additional information in the question.